# How to make 'sticky' posts in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still sort of new to Rails. I'm building a blog type website and would like to make some of my posts "sticky", just like Wordpress stickies (stick to the top).

I know you can order posts by its `created_at` column, which is what I'm doing now. But how would I have my "sticky" posts stay above my other posts no matter what its `created_at` date is?

Current code:

```
@posts = Post.all.order('created_at desc')
```

---

Everything's working fine now. There was a minor issue with my code

```
@posts = Post.order('sticky, created_at desc')
```

works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a boolean attribute `sticky` to your `Post` model and then do:

```
@posts = Post.order('sticky, created_at desc')
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the 'sticky' is actually a "post type" (string) & not a boolean

Comment: @Jon In that case you can do two queries: one for stickies and one for non-stickies. Or change your schema to have a boolean attribute `sticky` like I suggest above.

Comment: @Jon Then you've already done this wrong. You want your "sticky" column to be sortable, and using a single column set to "sticky", "normal" and "unpublished" is simply *wrong* for a whole host of reasons. Use state flags: You should have one boolean column, `sticky`, and one boolean column `published`.

Comment: I see your point. I already have a lot of booleans in some of my other tables & just didn't want to go 'boolean crazy'.. I'm chnaging it now so that I'll have 3 different booleans "sticky", "published", & "unpublished".. Thx for the heads up @meagar

Comment: @Jon You don't need two booleans for "published" and "unpublished". Your published posts are the ones where `published` is true. Your unpublished posts are the posts where `published` is false. The whole point of booleans is that they represent two states. Published/unpublished and sticky/not-sticky require two boolean fields, not four.

Comment: *slaps head* lol.. Ofcourse.. I think I'm going to get some sleep now.. Thanks @meagar

Comment: @Mischa I added the boolean & the sticky posts still aren't on top

Comment: @Jon What database are you using? You may need `Post.order('sticky desc, created_at desc')` instead. It depends how booleans are stored in your database.

Comment: @Mischa I'm using postgres

Comment: So, does it work if you try `sticky desc` instead of `sticky`? I don't know by heart how Postgres stored booleans... Please try.

Answer (score 0):

You have string attribute : `post_type (sticky, normal, or unpublished)`. If you are still using string attribute, try this :

```
@posts = Post.where('post_type not in (?)', 'unpublished').order('post_type desc, created_at desc')
```

**Note :**

1. `.where('post_type not in (?)', 'unpublished')`

   - not display post have unpublished post_type.
2. `.order('post_type desc, created_at desc')`

   - order `post_type` with descending (sticky, normal)  and
   - `created_at` with descending

But that is **not recommended**, You should use boolean attribute, example

```
t.boolean :sticky
# sticky : true , normal : false
t.boolean :publish
# publish : true , unpublish : false
```

And you can use this on your controller :

```
@posts = Post.where(:publish => true).order('sticky DESC, created_at DESC')
```

See example :

[Ruby on Rails 3.2.x - Sticky and Publish Post](https://gist.github.com/fauzieuy/6018070)

Comment: too late submit answer ... zzzzz

Comment: I'm using booleans now.. I have the exact same code as you've posted & still can't seem to get it to work. Since both of you gave the same answer, I'm assuming that the problem is on my end & am trying to find out what's wrong

Comment: @Jon you should add default value 'false' to boolean

Comment: mmm.. still not working.. I set all the booleans to false & made that the default. I made one post a sticky (double check by doing a 'count') and it's still not working

Comment: @Jon Can you show me what you're trying on your controller?, I have created [Ruby on Rails 3.2.x - Sticky and Publish Post](https://gist.github.com/fauzieuy/6018070), you could read it.

Comment: '@posts = Post.order('sticky DESC, created_at DESC')' is what I'm using. I'm also rendering my posts throught a js.erb file. Thank you for taking the time to write the post. I'm going to follow along to see what the problem is

Comment: Ok, it's definitely something wrong on my end because even ASC won't work. Sorry, it's a my mistake, I just have to figure out what it is. Again, thank you @anonymousxxx

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

In controller:

```
@sticky_posts = Post.where(sticky: true)
@common_posts = Post.where(sticky: false).order('created_at DESC')
```

In view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'post', locals: {posts: @sticky_post %>
<%= render :partial => 'post', locals: {posts: @common_post %>
```

Just make two query and it can do what you want.